# The upper bound of $L^2$ norm of the minimizer in an minimizing problem.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, bounded-variation

I am considering the following minimizing problem:
$$
u_m:= \operatorname{argmin}_{u\in BV(\Omega)}\{ \frac{1}{2} \|u-u_0\|_{L^2}^2 + t |u|_{TV}\}
$$
where $u_0\in BV(\Omega)\cap L^\infty(\Omega)$ and $t>0$ is a constant. $|\cdot|_{TV}$ denotes the total variation of $u$. ($\Omega\subset \mathbb R^2$ is open bounded smooth boundary)

I learned from the numerical simulation that 
$$
\|u_m\|_{L^2}\leq \|u_0\|_{L^2}
$$
but I can not prove it analytically. Please advise!

Comment: It is quite simple to prove $\|u_m\|_{L^2} \le 2 \, \|u_0\|_{L^2}$.

Comment: @gerw right I know. But the key point is I don't want that "2" to be there. It's important for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found three different ways to prove your inequality, but they are essentially the same. For convenience, let $t = 1$.

1. For $s \ge 0$, define
   $$f(s) = \frac12 \, \| s \, u -u_0\|_{L^2}^2 + |s \, u|_{TV}.$$
   Then,
   $$0 = f'(1) = (u - u_0, u) + |u|_{TV}.$$
2. The optimality conditions of your problem yield
   $$0 \in u - u_0 + \partial |\cdot|_{TV}(u).$$
   Here, $\partial |\cdot|_{TV}$ is the subdifferential of the total variation. Hence,
   $$|0|_{TV} \ge |u|_{TV} + (u_0 - u, 0-u).$$
3. Consider $u_0$ in your problem as a parameter. Then, the mapping $u_0 \mapsto u$ is the proximal point mapping of the TV-norm (w.r.t. the $L^2$-norm). Hence, it is Lipschitz (in $L^2$) with constant $1$. Since the solution with $u_0 = 0$ is $u = 0$, we have $\|u - 0\|_{L^2} \le \|u_0 - 0\|_{L^2}$.

Note that the strength of the results is decreasing, whereas the generality is increasing.

Comment: This is indeed awesome! From your method $1$ we can also show the strict less right? since $|u|_{TV}>0$.

Comment: Yes, if $u$ is not constant. It also follows for method 2, since you can obtain similarly $|2\,u|_{TV} \ge |u|_{TV} + (u_0 - u, 2\,u - u)$. And then, methods 1 and 2 are actually the same...